# create users with apex_util.create_user problem

Tags: oracle-apex, createuser

I want to create a user in apex from db(in oracle).
this is my code:

```
declare
   l_workspace_id number;
   l_group_id     number;
begin
   l_workspace_id := apex_util.find_security_group_id('MS');

   apex_util.set_security_group_id(l_workspace_id);

   l_group_id := apex_util.get_group_id('Developer');

   apex_util.create_user(p_user_name           => 'MS',
                      p_first_name          => 'Mona',
                      p_last_name           => 'Sh',
                      p_email_address       => 'ms@...',
                      p_group_ids           => l_group_id,  
                      p_web_password        => 'MS',
                      p_default_schema      => 'MS',
                      p_change_password_on_first_use  => 'N');

end;
```

It runs successfully, but I cant see the user in apex application in web.(workspace name, schema name and username are MS)
what is problem?

Comment: Does this API require a commit? Were you checking in the UI? What about a select from the apex_workspace_apex_users view in that session?

Comment: Did a quick test. This procedure doesn't do an implicit commit so user will not be visible in app until the transaction is committed.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. My problem is solved.